# Use globally defined fonts in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

What is the best way to enforce a standard set of fonts and sizes for an iOS-app?

Our app consists of about 150 xib-files, which of many have UILabels and UITextViews. The problem is that the font is set manually for each element in each of these xib-files, which leads to small inconsistencies here and there. I want them set globally one time, like **small**, **medium** and **large**, and then use those three defined fonts in the xib-files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [user defined runtime attributes](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/), which enable you set font name or font size, or layer border color etc for UIControl in Xcode.

Comment: Wow, that's a really powerful feature that I have overlooked! I like the answer by @JonGilkison as well, but for this project I will use runtime attributes, so I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use UIAppearance but, I believe, that this is only reliable in iOS 7+.

Otherwise, you could just subclass UILabel/UITextView, set the font in the init and then use those classes in your XIBs.

Your final option would be to use [Pixate Freestyle](http://www.freestyle.org) and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try FontReplacer like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fontreplacer
The source was removed on github but you can find in somewhere.

It does not immediately apply for xib files but working good at runtime.